# What is wrong with my 'selecting' code? (VB)

Tags: select, text, if-statement, textbox, focus

I have the following code in VB:

```
If TextBox1.Text = (Label2.Select(0, 1) Then
            TextBox2.Focus()
        End If
```

But it doesnt't work :(

This is what my code is supposed to do:

- If the text in texbox1 is the same as the first letter of label 2
- Then move cursor to textbox2

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write `Label2.Text.Substring(0,1)`.